# Writing a C++/CLI wrapper for GFLW

Tags: c#, c++, glfw

I am trying to write a C++/CLI wrapper for [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/). I created a CLR Class Library project called GLFWWrapper and added the `glfw3.lib` to Additional Dependencies, and also added the header files folder to Additional Include Directories.

My GLFWWrapper.h looks like this so far:

```
// GLFWWrapper.h

#pragma once

#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

using namespace System;

namespace GLFWWrapper {

    public ref class Window
    {
    public:
        Window(int width, int height, char * title);
    private:
        GLFWwindow * m_ptr;
    };
}
```

And my GLFWWrapper.cpp looks like this:

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "GLFWWrapper.h"

namespace GLFWWrapper {

    Window::Window(int width, int height, char * title) {
        if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {

        }
        else {
            m_ptr = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, nullptr, nullptr);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I try to compile it, I get the following warnings:

> GLFWWrapper.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000008) for 'GLFWwindow'; image may not run
>   GLFWWrapper.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100000B) for 'GLFWmonitor'; image may not run

What do they mean in my context and can this be problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
struct GLFWwindow {};
struct GLFWmonitor {};
```

before the:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

That will at least eliminate the warning. I am not set up to verify that it will execute properly but I assume that is easy enough to do for you and anyone else that needs to do what you are doing.